# Nuxeo studio jar file open in eclipse and deploy in server

Tags: java, nuxeo

Can I import nuxeo studio jar file with couple workflows  to eclipse make a configurations and deploy it as a bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done it, imported jar file to  eclipse, and can analyze xml files. I build it with cygwin like maven project and deployed it to server, works fine.